# Dequeueing cells in a Custom UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is more of an opinion I'm looking for than a question but..

I have a tableview that reads the cells from an array. I know this is NOT really encouraged but I wanted to do it this way to make my table very easy to configure by another developer.

My question lies in the cell dequeueing. This code WORKS perfectly however I just can't help but think how I have it written is improper. If anyone has any suggestions id love to hear them?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DialogViewSection *currentSection = self.sections[indexPath.section];
    DialogViewCell *currentCell = currentSection.sectionCells[indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    if ([currentCell isMemberOfClass:[EntryCell class]]) {
        DialogViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEntryCellIdentifier];
        cell = currentCell;
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        DialogViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kBooleanCellIdentifier];
        cell = currentCell;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not helping anyone by using this approach. Use standard cell dequeueing. It's better that the other developer learn how to do it properly. It's more efficient and the developer will know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: +1 to maddy's comment. Don't do that. That is a seriously bad idea, and won't help the other developer in any fashion. Any iOS developer worth their salt would toss your code out the window and run screaming. Anyone who thinks that's ok will be learning the WRONG way of doing things.

Comment: Lol ok guys. I will fix it! Didn't realize it would be that bad.

Comment: What Maddy said +1. This is a bad idea, and if you think you're helping your developer, you're deluding yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you will only make it more confusing for the next developer. I as a developer find it confusing to look at and can tell you that it's not the correct standard.

For your section cells, you really need to use your tableView's `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;` delegate method instead of returning a cell for a section. Because returning a cell that you want to portray as a section will not behave like how a section view should behave, and that is it hovering above your cells until the next section scrolls up. Check your contacts application on your iOS device to see how section views should behave in most general cases.

You will also want to dequeue cells the normal way too, let your UITableview handle it. It will also allow for other developers to understand what is going on straight away.

**Just as an idea:**

Consider using a multidimensional dictionary containing arrays to store an index of your sections and cell data al in one place Such a data model might look something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary index{
    "Section 1" = array(
                   section cell,
                   array(
                       Cell 1,
                       Cell 2,
                       Cell 3,
                   )
                },
    "Section 2" = array(
                   section cell,
                   array(
                       Cell 1,
                       Cell 2
                   )
                },
    "Section 3" = array(
                   section cell,
                   array(
                       Cell 1,
                       Cell 2,
                       Cell 3,
                       Cell 4
                   )
                }
}
```

Such an array can be created by having all your sections stored in an NSDictionary with an array storing your section cell in the first element of the array and in your second element you can store another array containing all your cells associated to that array.

I dont recommend you storing CUSTOM CELLS in an array and instead store THE DATA that will populate your cells instead.

Comment: Alright this makes sense, I will fix it up this approach. Thanks

Comment: Ok great, If it all made sense, then do mark this post for other users to see. Goodluck with implementing it all.

Comment: Sorry forgot to do that! Points are all yours

Comment: @DBoyer Cheers and goodluck